# Naming of type parameters in java

Tags: java, naming, generics

We all know that it is good to use descriptive identifier names. However, the convention in java is to use a single letter for a type parameter identifier. The default most people go to is `T`, but if you are dealing with elements in a collection, you often see `E`. Now I can see how it makes sense to use single letter identifiers for unbounded type parameters, since they can really be anything, so you have no information to be represented by the identifier.

But suppose you had two bounded type parameters, say `T extends Iterable<Integer>` and `S extends Consumer<Integer>`, wouldn't it make more sense to use more descriptive identifiers than `T` or `S` so you don't confuse them? You might be able to get away with using, say, `I` and `C`, but people would never (in my ideal world) be so terse with variable identifiers. So why are people so terse with type parameter identifiers? Or is the convention of single character type parameter identifiers not as pervasive as I imagine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some merit to single-letter type parameters

1. They're short which is fortunate as type params crop up in many places when writing generic code.
2. They are effectively in a different namespace from actual classes.

Of course, my first point is moot as Java doesn't care much about conciseness. But the second point avoids a real problem. Consider this piece of code:

```
Entry<Key, Value> e = new Entry<>(...);
```

I would start searching for the interfaces or classes `Entry`, `Key`, and `Value` which would lead nowhere as a few hundred lines before, all of these have been declared as type parameters. But no Java programmer would ever expected `E<K, V>` to refer to actual classes.

If we do not want to use the single-uppercase-letter naming convention, then we either have to surrender the discernability of actual types and type parameters, or we can switch to another convention e.g. using Hungarian Notation. Then, `IFoo`, `CFoo`, and `PFoo` would clearly refer to different kinds of types.

This is not a usable solution as the builtin Java types do not follow such a convention. For the sake of uniformity it is probably better to stick with a suboptimal but widespread solution rather than inventing your own.

The importance of naming type parameters can also be overemphasized, and it is quite possible to understand their meaning given some context, and sufficient documentation.

Comment: Ok so basically it can get confusing to differentiate between type parameters and class or interface identifiers. I think what I would do is have my type parameters be all caps. This would be consistent with built-in types, and there should be little confusion of type parameters and global constants (which are often in all caps as well). But I guess it is probably best to just go with the flow and choose single character identifiers. If it were really that big of a deal I guess people would be doing something different by now. I will wait a little bit and then accept.

Comment: +1 - I used to be the strict naming guy that insisted on fully typed names.  Then I realised none of my co-workers understood what was going on, so I went back to the industry convention.